# Todo list using google app engine tutorials in java?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to build a simple todo list using google app engine in java.
I am very new to google app engine that it will be really nice if there's any tutorial to follow..
Can anyone suggest me a good tutorial for this uses java?
Thank you

Comment: Not voting down, but would be more appropriate if you ask a specific question. This is too generic and won't help people guide you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Google App Engine Tutorial for Java](http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html) from Lars Vogel - it describes the creation of a TODO web application storing data via JPA.

For more complex example have a look at [MemWords source code](http://code.google.com/p/memwords/). It's free online password manager you can see in action at http://memwords.appspot.com/

Comment: Not exactly, but it shouldn't be difficult to rewrite these tutorials to persist data with JDO. Just look at Google's [Using JDO](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/).

Comment: Try [**GWT Tutorial**](https://sites.google.com/site/gwt2tutorial) which shows how to develop apps for Google App Engine with **JDO**.